# Logfile reformatting with regex

Tags: bash, logging, grep, reformat

I'm using grep to filter certain lines from a log file and present them to my conky config.
The log file is /var/log/messages.
The entries pertain to UFW block events.

The trouble is that I only care about certain strings of each line.
I can grep the only the UFW blocks, but the line is too long to fit in conky.
Even if conky were not part of the equation, learning to only show pieces of a log line would benefit me in future.

I have got somewhere by using the following:

`grep -Ewoh '(IN=([a-z]){4,})|((DST|SRC)=(([0-9]){1,3}\.){3,}([0-9]){1,3})|(PROTO=[a-z]{2,6})|((SPT|DPT)=[0-9]{1,5})' /var/log/messages`

This ugly-looking regex is filtering for entries (like) this:

```
IN=wlan0
SRC=10.10.123.23
DST=192.168.41.23
PROTO=TCP
SPT=443
DPT=41080
```

Which (nearly) line-for-line is as such:

```
'
IN=([a-z]){4,}
(DST|SRC)=(([0-9]){1,3}\.){3,}([0-9]){1,3}
PROTO=[a-z]{2,6}
(SPT|DPT)=[0-9]{1,5}
'
```

The problem is that this produces a new line for each matching word, where I just want the filtered strings of each line, in their line.

```
$ grep -Ewoh '(IN=([a-z]){4,})|((DST|SRC)=(([0-9]){1,3}\.){3,}([0-9]){1,3})|(PROTO=[a-z]{2,6})|((SPT|DPT)=[0-9]{1,5})' /var/log/messages
IN=wlan
SRC=103.81.76.20
DST=172.31.77.54
SPT=443
DPT=41080
$
```

I'd rather not use a very complicated awk method unless I can walk back into it a few months later and remember it easily. awk *is* incredible, but it can be difficult to digest if you drop the ball just once!

*Thank you.*

Comment: Just noticed I can see a problem with the IN/interface regex. Ignore that for now!

Comment: Would you please provide a sample input (before filtering) and the expected output? BTW you may also have a problem in `PROTO=[a-z]{2,6}`, which should not limit to lower case letters.

Comment: _ the filtered strings of each line, in their line_: What do you mean by **in their line**? With _grep_, you specify patterns. You can choose whether you want to see each line where a pattern matches, or just the matched patterns (which is what you did by providing the `-o` option). What else do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, instead of the list provided by `grep -o`, you want to remove non matching strings, and print only matching strings, in place. Ie. in the lines and order they appear.

Using `gawk`'s `FPAT`:

```
gawk -v FPAT='my-regex' '$1=$1'
```

- Replace `my-regex` with the regex for strings you want to see.
- This will print the matches on each line, in order, delimited by a space.
- Add `-v OFS=` to remove the space, or for example, `-v OFS=', '` to change the delimiting string.
- You were using `grep -w` to match a whole word. You can do this in a gawk regex by using `\<` and `\>` for left and right word boundary (respectively).
- For example, add parentheses and word boundaries around the whole list of 'or' operators (`|`):
- `-v FPAT='\<((IN=([a-z]){4,})|((DST|SRC)=(([0-9]){1,3}\.){3,}([0-9]){1,3})|(PROTO=[a-z]{2,6})|((SPT|DPT)=[0-9]{1,5}))\>'`
- Note the bugs in your regex, such as tshiono commented, which won't match `PROTO=TCP`.

Comment: Thanks dan. gawk's FPAT is a perfect solution.
In the end I needed this command `cat /var/log/messages | gawk -v FPAT='((IN=[a-z]{2,5}[0-9]{1,2})|((DST|SRC)=(([0-9]){1,3}\.){3,}([0-9]){1,3})|(PROTO=[A-Z]{2,6})|((SPT|DPT)=[0-9]{1,5}))' '$1=$1'`

Which in answer to tshiono question, filters this:
`2022-02-08T15:30:10.230933+11:00 HOST kernel: [25944.688910] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=MAC SRC=PRIVATE DST=192.168.0.132 LEN=131 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=20845 PROTO=UDP SPT=30983 DPT=6907 LEN=111`
To this: `IN=wlan0 SRC=PRIVATE DST=192.168.0.132 PROTO=UDP SPT=30983 DPT=6907`